# Solve a system of differential equations in MATLAB when one function is known

Tags: function, matlab, equation, ode45

I have an equation:

[image: equation]

where `t` and `v(t)` are known. I have to find `u(t)`.

I wrote a program:

```matlab
function dudt = odefcn(t, u, v)
    dudt = v.^2 * u + v .* u + diff(v);
end

[t,u] = ode45(@(t,u) odefcn(t,u,v), tspan, u0);
```

The problem is that the function `v(t)` is a vector that has the same dimension as `t`. Finally, I see the error that dimensions do not match.

Comment: You could use [gradient(v)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html) to compute the derivative; it returns a vector of the same size as `v`. Both `diff` and `gradient` return an approximation of the dericative dv/dt, only if the step size in `t` is one.